# No internet after changing mac on Kali Linux

Tags: networking, kali-linux, internet

I'm running Kali Linux on VirtualBox. I'm using bridged adapter, WNA with adapter type Intel Pro/1000 MT in the VBox network settings. 
My internet works flawlessly as long as my eth0 mac is the same as the one in the Network settings (option to change it is disabled, grayed out). Whenever I change my mac either by using macchanger or by turning off the network interface, changing it and turning the interface on, I lose the connection. After changing mac I'm also not able to ping the host and vice versa, 0 packets received. What should I do to make it work?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

-This happens it is perfectly normal because you are making changes "even if in a virtual device" of the same physical address, the connection drops ... if you want to make the change MAC and still have connection should make the change before connect, because unfortunately this is it.

Comment: It doesn't work even if you have shut your eth0 down before the change.

Answer (score 0):

Keep trying different mac addresses, currently connected to wifi with spoofed mac after several attempts. `macchanger` generated a mac address which didn't work and was `10.something.something.something`
Grabbed a mac address from an old `wireshark` capture and it works great, getting me the usual `192.168.1.something` on my wifi.
Some bits of the address represent features.

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked for me even in a VM

Change `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`

FROM `managed=false`

TO `managed=true`

Then create a script `mac.sh` In this script put

```
#!/bin/bash
service NetworkManager stop
ifconfig eth0 down
macchanger -r eth0
ifconfig eth0 up
service NetworkManager start
```

Don't forget to run `chmod +x mac.sh` Then just run `./mac.sh`

Comment: NOTE : I have found that your Network must be set to NAT for this solution to work. If you need to use Bridged just set up a script to change the MAC address of the vm on startup